# Can a login message text be added via Azure AD?

Tags: azure-active-directory

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/interactive-logon-message-text-for-users-attempting-to-log-on

Can an interactive login be done for every staff member's windows account via Azure AD?

Answer (score 0):

•   Yes, you can surely configure an interactive logon message for those devices that are joined to Azure AD domain and are logged in with cloud user identity. Also, please note that this can also work in **Hybrid Azure AD joined devices**, i.e., devices joined to on-premises AD as well as Azure AD. For this purpose, you will have to enroll these devices in **Intune MDM** by purchasing Intune licenses for your Azure AD joined devices.

•   Through the Intune portal, you will have to follow the below steps to configure the interactive logon message for Intune enrolled Azure AD joined Windows devices: -

a.  Sign in to the https://endpoint.microsoft.com/. To create a new Configuration profile, Select Devices --> Windows --> Configuration profiles --> Create profile.

b.  In the **‘Create a profile’** section, Select Platform as Windows 10, and later and in Profile, Select Profile Type as Settings catalog. Click on **‘Create’** button.

c.  On the Basics tab, enter a descriptive name, such as Interactive logon Message for users. Optionally, enter a Description for the policy, then select Next.

d.  In Configuration settings, under Settings catalog, click Add settings, then select **‘Local Policies security options’** to see all settings in this category.

e.  Then select Interactive logon Message Title for Users Attempting to Log On, Interactive logon Message Text for Users Attempting To Log On and then after adding your settings, click the cross mark at the right-hand corner to close the settings picker.

f.  Then under Assignments, In Included groups, click Add groups and then choose Select groups to include one or more groups. Click Next to continue. You can assign a tag to filter the profile to specific IT groups in-Scope tags. Add scope tags (if required) and click Next. In Review + create, review your settings. When you select Create, your changes are saved, and the profile is assigned.

In this way, we can configure the interactive logon message for Azure AD logged in users on Windows devices.